# how to post a github PR that sets the base branch to release_

Tags: github

Developers keep making the mistake on hotfixes to release branches in github.  Here are the steps we have right now

- git checkout --track origin/release_xxxx (make sure you are on the release branch)
- git checkout -b yourName/yourTicketNumber (the hotfix branch)
- Modify your code
- Post a PR
- **modify the PR's base branch back to release_xxx**

I am wondering if there is a slick way on the last step that once in a while gets missed to automatically use the branch it was branched from instead of main?

Perhaps I just need to create a postHotfix.sh and do the work in there but then people need github tools installed.  Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of an automatic solution, but you can change the base branch when raising your PR in the GitHub UI:

[image: Change the "base" option to the branch you want]

If you're using the GitHub CLI, you can add a `-B` (or `--base`) branch as an argument: https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create

Comment: yes, we have been trying to get people to do that @James I should have taken a picture like you did.   I guess github cli is the only option.  thanks!!!!!